# SSRS- charts colour coding

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS solution for SQL 2005 and 2008.

I am showing output in the form of chart- column chart with each column representing different database.

Is there a way to display each column in different color?

Regards

Manjot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula to set the colour of each column, but that would work best if you knew what the individual series values ('databases'?) were going to be.

Right-click on your chart and bring up its properties. Now switch to the Data tab and select the first item in the `Values` list. Click the `Edit...` button to show the properties for the values (the columns) in your chart. Over on the `Appearance` tab there's a `Series Style...` button which takes you to another dialog.

On this new `Style Properties` dialog, switch to the `Fill` tab. That's where you set the colour for each of your columns. This can be a formula, so you might make it something like:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Database.Value = "master", "Blue",
    Fields!Database.Value = "msdb", "Red",
    "Green")
```

If you don't know in advance which 'databases' are going to be represented on the chart, this method won't work very well. In that case you might be able to come up with a formula which hashes the database name and comes up with a colour to match. That sounds like an interesting challenge, so add to your question if you need help doing something like that.

**Edit**

I just got a hash-based-colour-scheme working. It's a pretty nasty piece of code, but it did manage to get me a unique colour for every (string valued) column. Perhaps someone can come up with a better algorithm and post it here. Here's mine:

```
="#" & left(Hex(Fields!Database.GetHashCode()), 6)
```

So that's getting the HashCode for the string (a numeric value) and converting it to hex, then taking the leftmost six characters and prepending it with a "#" sign. That gives us a string that looks like a colour value (eg #AB12F0).

Comment: Great.
I will try it tonight.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: I just gave it a go, but I've been unable to make it work with the Switch() function. Try it with nested Iif() functions instead if you have the same problem - that worked ok for me.

Comment: If you control the database structure you can add a colour field to the table and use that, allowing you to have consistent colouring across all charts. For example, each of our departments gets assigned a colour and this colour is used in all charts so the comparisons are easy to see without having to keep referring to the legend to see what department is what colour in this chart.